# The content doesn't sit horizontally in the web page

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

This code is for a footer. Originally the different columns sat next to each other.(col-md-4 x 3) However I edited the code and for some reason the columns are on top of one another. The content is meant to sit 3 columns in one row  making up the 12 columns.

```css
footer {
  background-color: #000000;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
  padding-top: 2%;
}

.westernaustralianmuseum {
  color: #AD8A51;
}

.footercontact {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.footeroptions {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.footerlocation {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<footer class="container-fluid">
  <!-- div for the main image to stretch s to the edge of the page-->
  <div class="container">
    <!-- div to hold the content in the middle of the page-->
    <div class="row">
      <!-- a row that gives us access to the BS columns-->
      <div class="col-md-4 footercontact">
        <h3>Contact</h3>
        <p>Email: reception@museum.wa.gov</p>
        <p>Phone: 1300 134 081</p>
        <h3>Follow us</h3>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="instagram icon">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="twitter icon">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="facebook icon">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="youtube icon">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 footeroptions">
        <p><span class="westernaustralianmuseum">Western Australian Museum</span></p>
        <p>Membership</p>
        <p>Donate</p>
        <p>About</p>
      </div>
      <!-- row -->
      <div class="col-md-4 footerlocation">
        <h3>Location & Hours</h3>
        <ul class="list-inline justify-content-center">
          <li class="list-item">47 Cliff Street</li>
          <li class="list-item">Fremantle, WA</li>
          <li class="list-item">6160</li>
          <li class="list-item">Open Daily:</li>
          <li class="list-item">0930Am to 0500Pm</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- row -->
  </div>
  <!-- container -->
</footer>
</body>
```

I am still new here , thanks

Comment: What's "they"? Please revise your post title and question to be more clear. See [ask] for tips.

Comment: If you're referring to the columns, have you looked on a screen larger than 768px wide? See the full page demo above.

Comment: Protip: Instead of creating repetitious CSS for margin, use Bootstrap's [spacing utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/spacing/#margin-and-padding), or create _one_ class for top margin and name it semantically, like `margin-top-20`.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update on this, I figured it out. When you look at the code from VSC there are no extra div's but when you open it in the inspector of a browser it shows hidden divs. It has something to do with editing on wordpress. [image] [image] [image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).